# WIN API - Programm getting stuck while a button is selected

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am creating a simple software using WINAPI that reads the data from a sensor connected to a computer via USB.
In this software, I am implementing some functions like read mode, test mode, etc.

The problem that I am facing is that I am getting stuck while I select the button for continuous reading, the code follows below:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wp)
    {  
    case START_BUTTON:
        printf("START_BUTTON"); 

        while(SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_GETCHECK ,TRUE,0)== BST_CHECKED)
        {
            char* var = USB_Read();   //Get data from the sensor
            SetWindowText(hLux, var); //Display the data

            if (SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_GETCHECK ,TRUE,0)!= BST_CHECKED) //Check if the botton is no longer selected
            break;
        }

        break;
    }
    break;
```

I know that the problem is in the while-loop, when I press it all the program gets stuck, only the data is being displayed correctly, the other controls get like frozen.

The question is: How could I display the data continuously and have access to the other controls at the same time?

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Please remove the language you aren't using from the tags

Comment: *"How could I display the data continuously and have access to the other controls at the same time?"* - By offloading the data retrieval off of the UI thread.

Comment: @IInspectable, I have no idea how to use thread, I am just beginner with winapi

Comment: The loop you made cuts out the message loop execution. You can't remain inside the local while stopping the message pump. Change your code removing the while and replacing it with an `if`. This way you make a reading from usb each message loop run as before, but don't stop it, restoring the functionality of the UI system.

Comment: @Frankie_C, I tried it previously, in fact, the program stop to stuck, however, I have to click every time in the start button to refresh the read data.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes I am just checking about some sources about threads, and I could notice that it is exactly what I need. Do you have some tip how should I start or a reference book for studying ?

Comment: @GustavodaSilvaGhedim start by reading Microsoft's documentation: [Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processes-and-threads) and in particular [Multiple Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multiple-threads)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a thread of execution that reads the usb while the start is checked.
So we create a thread that is started in the program initialization, which run continuosly and reads usb each time it founds the button checked.

Now in the message loop you simply check or uncheck the button.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    (void)lpParam;    //make happy compiler for unused variable

    while (TRUE)     //Once created the thread runs always
    {
        //If checked reads usb for each iteration
        if(SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_GETCHECK ,0,0)== BST_CHECKED)
        {
            char* var = USB_Read();   //Get data from the sensor
            SetWindowText(hLux, var); //Display the data
            Sleep(1);    //Why this? to don't have a furious CPU usage
        }
    }
}


.....

//Winmain
    DWORD dwThreadId;    //thread ID in case you'll need it
    //Create and start the thread
    CreateThread( 
                    NULL,           // default security attributes
                    0,              // use default stack size  
                    ThreadFunction, // thread function name
                    NULL,           // argument to thread function 
                    0,              // use default creation flags 
                    &dwThreadId);   // returns the thread identifier

......

case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wp)
    {  
    case START_BUTTON:
        printf("START_BUTTON");
        if(SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_GETCHECK ,0,0)== BST_CHECKED)
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_SETCHECK ,BST_UNCHECKED, 0);
        else
            SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,START_BUTTON,BM_SETCHECK ,BST_CHECKED, 0);
        break;
    }
    break;
```

EDIT: I modified the program to check/uncheck the radio button.

Please note the usage of the `Sleep` function with a minimal value of 1ms. It is used to give back control to the OS to smooth the CPU usage. If in the function that reads the usb there are enough OS synch primitives it can be omitted (check cpu usage).